# Rake is too verbose, echos test command

Tags: ruby, rake, testunit

Rake is too verbose:

```
$ bundle exec rake test:units
/Users/jared/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /Users/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.....................................
```

This is what I want:

```
$ bundle exec rake test:units
.....................................
```

I still want to see test errors + failures, deprecation warnings, or arbitrary "stdout sentinels".

Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't get this without modifying the rake task and/or the test library. Just grep out the undesired lines.

```
bundle exec rake test:units | grep -vP "^(Started|Loaded|\/)"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like a solution that will automatically be shared with my colleagues.  Can I get rid of any of these lines without resorting to grep?

Comment: You could always write your own rake task in your project `Rakefile` that isn't as noisy but does the same thing. The output is exactly what you need to run, so you're already half-way there.