# Hide the list of files when running rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rake, rspec2, rspec-rails

When running `rake spec` on the command line for a large Rails project, I get a giant list of every rspec file that will be run.

Is there a way to hide that by default?

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/acceptance/replicators/activity_replicator_spec.rb ./spec/acceptance/replicators/template_replicator_spec.rb ./spec/authorization_rules/admin_authorization_rules_spec.rb ...
```

When I run just `rspec` (no rake call) I don't get this console output.

---

EDIT 1

Working from [phoet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100731/phoet)'s answer, I tried

```ruby
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.verbose = false
  t.warning = false
  t.rcov = false
end

task :default => :spec
```

This did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last time I did this, I had to `clear` the rake task first.

```
if defined? RSpec
  task(:spec).clear
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.verbose = false
  end
end
```

http://singlebrook.com/blog/disable-rspec-verbosity-to-hide-spec-list

Comment: I also think [rake is too noisy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678536/rake-is-too-verbose-echos-test-command) but haven't found a solution to that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get such an output when calling `rspec` because the output comes from the `RSpec::Core::RakeTask`.

It's possible to configure this class and set the verbose flag:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |t|
  t.verbose = false
end
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I still get the giant list of files being run after `ruby -S rspec`. I tried a couple of other options as well:
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
      t.verbose = false
      t.warning = false
      t.rcov = false
    end

    task :default => :spec

Comment: i guess you will have to write your own rake task for that. the rspec-rails task does not take any options: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake#L26