# Rake / Rspec: How to suppress / quiet / silent the first output line showing the command with --pattern ?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, serverspec

### Problem:

If I run `ServerSpec` (based on `RSpec`) through `Rake` with one of the following commands:

- `rake`
- `rake spec`
- `rake spec:all`
- `rake spec:<host>`
- `bundle exec rake`
- ...

Rake prints the command it executes to `stdout` before the serverspec output:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 
-I/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.6/lib:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib 
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.6/exe/rspec 
--pattern spec/<host>/\*_spec.rb
```

If I pass the target host manually to `rspec` like this ...

```
TARGET_HOST=<host> rspec
```

... the line does **NOT** show up.

### Question:

How can I prevent `Rake` from outputting this line / the command?

---

I'm using the default Rakefile generated by `serverspec-init`.

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

task :spec    => 'spec:all'
task :default => :spec

namespace :spec do
  targets = []
  Dir.glob('./spec/*').each do |dir|
    next unless File.directory?(dir)
    targets << File.basename(dir)
  end

  task :all     => targets
  task :default => :all

  targets.each do |target|
    desc "Run serverspec tests to #{target}"
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(target.to_sym) do |t|
      ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = target
      t.pattern = "spec/#{target}/*_spec.rb"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide the list of files when running rspec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935915/hide-the-list-of-files-when-running-rspec)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing from

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(target.to_sym) do |t|
  ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = target
  t.pattern = "spec/#{target}/*_spec.rb"
end
```

to

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(target.to_sym) do |t|
  ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = target
  t.pattern = "spec/#{target}/*_spec.rb"
  t.verbose = false
end
```