# How to silence `bundle exec rake` printing list of filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using `rspec-rails v3.0.2` in a Rails 4.x project. When I run `rake`, it prints the full command its executing (all the file paths) to STDOUT. How do I silence this?

The only other answer I'm seeing is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299828/986415), and I'm not sure how to apply that to `rspec-rails`. I played around briefly in the gem code, but was not able to figure out where to set `verbose` to false.

Comment: Actually, NOT ready to close. I added [this rake task](http://singlebrook.com/blog/disable-rspec-verbosity-to-hide-spec-list) to `lib/tasks/spec.rake` and it broke my Travis build

Comment: I was able to fix by preserving prerequisites noted [here](https://gist.github.com/jaredbeck/3148368#comment-1000308)